# How to calculate walk distance in meter after each 1/2 second in iOS application?

Tags: ios, location, distance

I am working on an iOS application in which I have to calculate the walk distance in meter in each 0.5 second and find turn(left & right) in a Office or shop. I want to show all this navigation on a plane UIView.
  If I think about `CLLocationmanager` than accuracy is not upto the mark.

So, suggest me any suitable solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: accuracy? Its used by all the world class app. You can go ahead without worry.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a timer every .5 seconds that calls a function that reads the location from a CLLocationManager object. Then calculate distance from last reading and get the compass direction from the CLLocationManager object.

> [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self
>   selector:@selector(getLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];